# listings line numbers work with one lstlisting but not another

Tags: listings, line-numbering

The first listing has its line numbers ignoring the stepnumber while the second is just fine. Guess it might have to do with using math mode but mathescape applies to both, so if that is the case it is not obvious what to do to me

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside]{book}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\small,
    keywordstyle=\ttfamily,
    identifierstyle=\ttfamily,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    stepnumber=5,
    numbersep=5pt,
    numberfirstline=true,
    firstnumber=1,
    mathescape=true
    }


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
g = $\infty$

for $v$ in vertices:
    s = $\emptyset$
    r = $\{v\}$
    pred[v] = $\emptyset$
    d[v] = $0$
    while not r == $\emptyset$:
        x = $x \in r$
        s = s $\cup$ x
        r = r $\setminus$ x
        for
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}
step = 1
res = new Graph()

def BFS(v,currentLength,maxLength):
    if currentLength < maxLength:
        if not label[v]:
            label[v] = step
            step = step + 1
        for w in Neighborhood(v):
            if label[w]:
                continue
            pred[w] = v
            res.Append(v,w)
            BFS(w,currentLength + 1, maxLength)

root = PickVertex()
BFS(root,0,k)
\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems that every line in which a math formula is present triggers numbering the next line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that is caused by a bug in the [listings](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) code. These line numbers are printed because the flag that tests to see whether the code line is the first line is never reset. If you add

```
\makeatletter
\gdef\lst@numberfirstlinefalse{\global\let\lst@ifnumberfirstline\iffalse}
\lst@AddToHook{Init}{\global\let\lst@ifnumberfirstline\iftrue}
\makeatother
```

to you code (after `\usepackage{listings}`) then you will get the expected result (the `\global` is missing in `lstmisc.sty`). (**Edit:** I just added the *Init* line above to fix the first line number issue mentioned in the comments below.)

[image]

Comment: I wonder whether changing the definition of `\lst@numberfirstlinefalse` as you did has side effects. Anyway, well done for tracking that down, Andrew. I'm gonna post a small bounty to attract attention (and upvotes) to your answer.

Comment: @Jubobs I realised that there is one side effect in that in the second code block above the first line number is *not* printed. When I have time I'll look and see if I can fix this -- each `listings` should just reset  `\lst@ifnumberfirstline`. There probably shouldn't be any other side effects as this seems to only be used for printing line numbers...but the code is sufficiently complicated that I can't be sure. In any case, I reported this to the package maintainers.

Comment: I'll have another look tomorrow. There may be something we can do with hooks. In any case, that sure looks like a bug. Whether someone on TeX.SX finds a solution or not, the maintainer should be contacted.

Comment: Works for me. The first line is not numbered, but the rest is fine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user60625 I just added the `\lst@AddToHook{Init}` line to my solution. This fixes the numbering of the first line. Let me know if this breaks anything else!

Comment: @jubobs I fixed  the first number issue. As you suggested, an appropriate hook fixed it.

Comment: @user60625 Consider upvoting Andrew's answer also; [accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: @Andrew It looks like `listings` got you... hooked! `;p` ... I'll see myself out...

Comment: indeed, it does fix the first line, too. thx alot and jupp, upvoting as well